# variable the loop doesn't increase

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Need to count updated data in the table, but $up stays 0. Data received from imported csv file.

```
$up=0;   
    do { //loop through the csv file
            if ($data[0]) {
                $res = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
                $check=false;
                for($i = 0; $array[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); $i++){

                    while ((condition)){
                            $check = true;
                            $i++;
                    };
                };
            if ($check) {
                $up++;//this does not work
                mysql_query("UPDATE ...");

            }
            else {
                mysql_query("INSERT ...");

            }
            }
        } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

there's code below do-while loop where I choose the file and get the messege about $up

```
<html>
...
<?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) {echo $up; } ?> 
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
  Choose your file: <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 
...
```

Comment: Have you tried `++$up`? Are you sure your `UPDATE` statement has been executed?

Comment: yes, i'm. table updates

Comment: By the way, stop using `mysql_*` functions, **they are deprecated**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: where you are accessing `$up` to see its value?

Comment: Where do you check for `$up` to says it stays 0?

Comment: What is `condition`? `$up` will only be incremented if `$check` is true, and `$check` will only be true if `condition` is met.... but what is `condition`?

Comment: Well, he said the table get UPDATED, so I guess the `condition` is met after all

Comment: I output the message after importing the file.
`<html>
...
<?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) {echo $up; }  ?> 
...
<html>`

Comment: I'm also somewhat concerned about `$i` being incremented several times in the code.... in the `for()` loop and also dependent on `condition`... bad variable naming at the very least

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see, i'm pretty sure that you are inserting and not updating.

> your $up is only executed in cas $check is true
>   And your $check is only true if every line in your query meets the (condition)

You should verify what you are doing in the while(condition)

```
              for($i = 0; $array[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); $i++){

                while ((condition)){
                        $check = true;
                        $i++;
                };
            };
```

Comment: why semicolon after while and for loop ?

Comment: the table get updated. actually i count inserted data as well. And now i think that problem is in the way i try to output `$up`

Comment: something is wrong in your code which is not visible to us, you are showing limited code, otherwise your input not meeting the conditions which is required to execute  $up++;